# can dropped voltage be greater than forward voltage?

Tags: led, diodes

What I know is:

forward voltage, Vf = The minimum voltage that is required to start current flow across the LED/Diode

dropped voltage, Vd = The voltage that is used/lost across the LED/Diode.

My question is, initially the equation should be Vf>Vd but can Vd>Vf be true at any moment?

Besides, please correct me if I have any misconception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, whenever the diode is conducting.

With greater \$V_d\$ the current across the diode increases exponentially, and if it exceeds the maximum the diode can handle, the diode is destroyed.

When the supply cannot sustain the current (e.g. because it is regulated somehow), the system will reach an equilibrium where a slight increase in \$V_d\$ would reduce the resistance of the diode, which in turn reduces \$V_d\$ because the ratio \$\frac{R_{diode}}{R_{supply}}\$ drops.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Vf is rather arbitrary, and can be as low as you like - as long as you're talking about arbitrarily low currents. In general, for semiconductors diodes which are forward biased, 
$$I_f = I_0 e^{kV_f}$$
where $I_0$ is a scaling factor, and k depends on a bunch of things like material and temperature.

For "regular" diodes (silicon signal diodes) Vf is usually about .6 to .7 volts at a handy current level like 1 mA.

For LEDs, Vf depends on things like the LED material, and is usually specified at a nominal operating current like 10 or 20 mA. It is usually in the range of 1.5 volts (early red LEDs) to 3 to 3.6 volts (for 1 to 10 mA).

However, for greater currents the voltage drop does get greater.

So, your terminology is non-standard. Vf, in your terms, is not actually a threshold voltage, but rather a convenient way to characterize normal operation. The actual voltage during actual operation (Vd in your terms) can be either greater or less than the reference Vf, depending on what current level is used.

Answer (score 1):

What you're referring to is the [piecewise linear model](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Diode_modelling#/Piecewise_linear_model).

I think the Vf you refer to is the threshold voltage, or Vt, while the Vd is the voltage across the diode.

Vd can surely be greater than Vf, unless you're using the ideal diode model (no series resistance) in which case Vd=Vf for any possible forward current.